# What is the default block size of s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, parquet

I am writing a parquet file in s3. I have to be aware of s3 block size so I can set by row group size accordingly. as 1 row group size = default s3 block size. (default row group size in parquet in 128MB, But if try to get row offsets from  row groups meta, then I am getting that each row group consumes around 116MB. Why is it so  ?

For example: 148.7 MB file make 2 row groups

```
row group 1:     RC:2870100 TS:429678457 OFFSET:4 
row group 2:     RC:759588 TS:108434365 OFFSET:123729384
```

each row group consumes approximately 116MB data.

Comment: S3 is a object based storage so the only limit that applies is to a file size which is 5TB. What are you trying to achieve using S3?

Comment: I am trying to read each row group in each task so parallelism increase. But this is not the case. I have given defualt size of each row group to be 128MB. But i find that row group size may be less that that. Why is it so ?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned the file size is not inherently limited by S3 to this level.

Though you don't mention how you write to S3, the way you write is the likely suspect here.

A simple example would be that if you write with Spark, and do this in parallel.

Though I have not tested whether spark automatically parallelizes writes, a simple first step would be to set the parallelism to 1, regardless of which application you use to write.

---

Two things that could help validate that this is the right solution:

1. Upload a file to S3 with a different tool that does not do parallel processing, or even manually
2. Write with the application to a different location that is not S3.